# Que tipo de variables numericas puedo usar en Python?

Tags: base-de-datos

Estoy empezando a usar Python y algunos algoritmos me resultan dificiles de identificar o combinarlos...

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. 1. Centra tu pregunta en un problema particular. 2. Describe qué específicamente no estás comprendiendo. Pulsa en [edit] para agregar más detalles.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.